# Redirect a range of IPs using RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I am redirecting all users except for the IP 12.345.678.90 using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^12\.345\.678\.90
RewriteRule $ /maintenance [R=302,L]
```

What syntax would I use to allow a range? In my Allow list I have:

```
Allow from 123.45.678.90/28
```

Would it work if I just update the REMOTE_HOST line to:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^12\.345\.678\.90/28
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You probably want the `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` to match against, but you can't use CIDR notation as the `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` is *literally the remote address* and you can use a regular expression to try to match against it. So for 123.45.67.89/28, (123.45.67.80 - 123.45.67.95), you'd have to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.8[0-9]$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.9[0-5]$
```

Comment: If you want to match a wider range - e.g., indeterminate third and fourth octets - you could do `!^123\.45\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$` -- this will match any number from 0-255 in the third and fourth octets but let you define the first half of the IP. Recently had to do this on a WordPress I was developing, to allow WordPress JetPack servers to connect in to the XML-RPC endpoint while still redirecting regular visitors to a separate site.

Comment: Very inefficient `RewriteCond`, [@zts answer is way better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024233/797495)

Comment: This was answered when Apache 2.2 was widely used, now everything's 2.4 so using the expr is way better

Answer (score 39):

If you're using Apache HTTPD 2.4 or later, you can use [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) to match REMOTE_ADDR against a CIDR mask.

The short form looks like this:

```
RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.1.0/24'"
```

The following longer form is also available, but the documentation suggests it is less efficient:

```
RewriteCond expr "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '192.168.1.0/24'"
```

That makes the full solution to your example something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance$
RewriteCond expr "! -R '12.345.678.90/28'"
RewriteRule $ /maintenance [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Question: Could you give an example to the short form? It's unclear how it references `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`, whereas `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` is explicitly noted in the longer form.

Comment: @plusjeff I'm not sure what you mean - the example of the short form is included above.  From the linked documentation, -R is `Same as "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch ...", but more efficient`.

Comment: Is `-R` in the short form representative of `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`? If so, how does one use the high performance short form for checking a different variable (i.e. say I wanted to check a variable called `%{CLIENT_IP}` with the short form? If I use a different variable, do I always have to use the longer form?

Comment: Yes, for other variables you will have to use the longer form.  `-R` is specifically for `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I find it still very relevant. An alternative that does allow CIDR notation is the following (example is in a virtualhost apache conf file):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    .
    .
    .
    <Files maintenance>
        Require all denied
        Require ip 12.345.678.90/28
    </Files>
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

As a sidenote, I *suspect*, without having done any testing or finding any evidence, that this method is "faster" than the `RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.1.0/24'"` methods mentioned.

This is for the simple reason that at this high level there appears to be less computational steps involved.

N.B. a requester from an IP that is denied will see a "Permission denied" or "Forbidden" type response. You can make this prettier by adding in a custom 404 page that responding with a 200/OK (this way Google won't penalise your domain). The 200/OK has to be the first line of your custom 404 page. For example in PHP, the first line would read:

```
<?php header("Status: 200 OK"); ?>
```

You'd want to do this for a legit page you redirect to. Actual 404s should respond with 404 to keep us from ending up with a ton of useless search engine results down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in .htaccess. It's working.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.[0-255]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the following which allows partial address matching. In Your `virtualHost/htaccess` file

```
SetEnvIf HOST "siteYouAreworkingON.com" ACCESS_CONTROL<br>
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "list of full or partia ipadresses separated by |"<br>
RewriteCond %{ENV:ACCESS_CONTROL} 1<br>
RewriteRule .* http://gohere.instead [L,R]
```

Hope it helps.