# Iptables : How to block (handle) X-Forwarded-For addresses?

Tags: reverse-proxy, firewall, iptables, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

*(I'm in fact, on the CentOS behind AWS ELB. But i don't want this question to be specific for AWS ELB only, but for the general ground.)*

I'm working on a CentOS 6.5 box, which is behind a loadbalancer which only passes the `X-Forwarded-For` IPs to me. As a web server, I know the bad IPs coming in, and I need to block them, from by server itself. (Assuming there is no any IPS/IDS/Firewall in front, to rely on.)

So far, I don't know (I can't) block those bad IPs by my `iptables` because there's no real IP, but only X-Forwarded-For IPs passed to me. (So what I do is, I am using the `.htaccess` to block. And it works)

How to achieve this by the proper firewall level please?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to do the same thing.  I've got a very long list of IP addresses to block in CIDR format, and converting it to regular expressions to use in a .htaccess file just doesn't seem like the right thing to do. And you know that in terms of processor load, regular expressions in .htaccess aren't even in the same galaxy as the integer bit-fiddling that iptables can do. But I don't believe that it's possible to use iptables for this. Iptables runs in the kernel, and it blocks the incoming IP addresses at a low level, before any header is read.

In my case, I'm only using the load balancer as a convenient way to handle https requests, I don't really need to balance a heavy load across multiple webserver instances. So what I've been considering is running a separate instance with nginx reverse proxy to handle https for my apache webserver, adding the X_FORWARDED headers exactly like the AWS load balancer does. That way I can use iptables on the instance running nginx, and I don't have to touch my apache configuration or webapps that have been running behind the load balancer.

You lose the redundancy of multiple IP addresses for the load balancer itself, as well as integration with AWS Cloud Front to balance backend load, but you gain ability to use iptables and you can offload processing of static content from apache, perhaps improving your response time. Since nginx is said to be much lighter-weight than apache for simple request processing, you shouldn't need much muscle on that instance. I wonder if AWS load balancers are actually just instances running nginx. If you look at the pricing, the hourly cost of a load balancer is roughly the same as a t2.small linux instance.

I haven't tried this yet myself, as nginx configuration is brand new to me, and it would require buying and installing an SSL certificate instead of using the wonderfully simple and convenient certificate manager.

I wonder if AWS would consider user feature-requests to be able to configure load balancers with iptables...

UPDATE: I just posted [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228495) in the AWS EC2 forum.

UPDATE 2: My feature request to AWS asking for a feature to configure iptables for the load balancer got answered with an explanation of how to use a network ACL to block requests originating from any CIDR in a list from reaching the load balancer. To me, that's just as good a solution. The OP was looking for a solution not specific to AWS, and this doesn't meet that criterion. If you have this problem with some server that is behind a reverse proxy, it simply isn't possible to use that server's iptables-style firewall to block incoming requests based on the original IP address - the firewall needs to decide whether to block a request long before it reads the headers, which is the only place that the original requesting address can be found. If you're on AWS, you can use a network ACL. Otherwise you'd need to have full control over the server performing the reverse proxy, and put the firewall rules on that server.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do pattern matching with IP Tables: http://wiztelsys.com/Article_iptables_bob2.html

So you'd have to do that for example:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport <port> -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: <ip>" --algo bm -j DROP
```

"-m": matching type = string

"--string": what string

"--algo bm": Boyer-Moore algorithm for pattern matching

Comment: Coming back to my own answer: don't lose your time trying to achieve this if you're using https, as the content will be encrypted...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention .htaccess it sounds like you're using Apache Webserver, so I'd recommend adding these rules there instead of in iptables.  The basic way of blocking based on X-Forwarded-For in Apache is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} ^171.42.6.123$
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Since the IP address is just a string being matched against then you can specify all sorts of regular expressions in your condition.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653461/redirect-a-range-of-ips-using-rewritecond) for an example of doing that.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the answer. But as i mentioned, actually i already am using .htaccess to block (as a last resort so far). But what i want is (not to use .htaccess and) to use Firewall (iptables) properly, instead.