# Custom Error Page Intranet Sub Domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a simple web app that resides on an web server. The setup is Apache, PHP, MySQL, Windows Server 2012 R2. The server resides on our internal network behind a corporate firewall.

The web app is only accessible on our **internal network** via the URL *www.webapp.example.com*

When someone attempts to access this URL externally (i.e at home) they receive a generic error message in their client browser, such as with Chrome in the following screenshot;

[image]

My question, is there any way I can create a **custom error page** so that when someone attempts to access *www.webapp.example.com* outside our network they will see a custom error, something simple like;

> This application is only available within the www.example.con network

We do own www.example.com and it's publically accessible over the internet, however the subdomain *www.webapp.example.com* is only accessible internally.

I'm not sure if this is something I have to configure on the web server, the .htaccess file, or elsewhere? Ideally I only want to allow access for a range of IP's (123.456.xxx.xxx), all others should see the custom error page.

Quite new to custom error handling so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RewriteCond and %{REMOTE_HOST}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654793/1992669) to target everything but your internal ip addresses:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.webapp.example.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.456\..*
  RewriteRule $ /no_public_access.html [L]

  Alias /no_public_access.html /path/to/no_public_access.html

  # …
</VirtualHost>
```