# Conditional RedirectMatch based on IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I use this RedirectMatch with limiting by IP address?

This is what I have right now, and it works as is: 
    `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1`

```
`RedirectMatch 302 ^/dir/.*$ http://mysite.org/myotherdir`
```

I want this to work only if *not* accessed from two different IP addresses. A visit from any other IP address should execute this code in my .htaccess.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A question like this has been asked and answered at StackOverflow. Check this: [.htaccess redirect to all IP's but mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985502/htaccess-redirect-to-all-ips-but-mine) .

Comment: That example doesn't work for me. I'm still redirected even though I'm accessing from my home computer.