# Avoid to access page from external network?

Tags: php

I have created some php pages which show data from some excel files.

I access those pages using internal IP address at the office where all PC's are connected on the same network. I access those pages from my home using external IP address.

So my question is, how do I put a password or protect my php page access from external network?

i.e. When I access php webpage from my home, it should ask for a password - how do I accomplish this?

eg:        hello.php

```
<?php
    echo"hello world";
?>
```

I want to put password to this php file or if I access it using external ip address then it should ask for password.

Comment: htaccess is your friend

Comment: actully i did that...but it is for internal ip address...
i dnt want to put pwd to internal network but want to put for external n\w

Answer (score 0):

Just define your IP available in your office, then block others.

```
$white_list = array('8.8.8.8', '1.1.1.1');

if (! in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $white_list))
{
    header('Location: mypasswordpage.php');
}
```

Comment: how to implement it?
and whether i hv to define external ip addrs there?means in array?

Comment: Use an htaccess to dispatch all your requests to your index.php file. Or, create a "check_access.php" file, and include it in every files you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in PHP you could use:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != [YOUR OFFICE IP HERE]) {
    // die or throw an exception
}
```

There are also plenty of security components. See the major frameworks:

[Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

[Zend 2](http://framework.zend.com/)

You can also configure apache to knock back requests based on IP. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985502/htaccess-redirect-to-all-ips-but-mine)