# Keep old website running while configuring a new website

Tags: redirect

I have my website and I want it to be online for customers.

In the mean time I want to upload wordpress to the same domain and start configuring it, but without anyone seeing that.

My website has a simple structure (index.php, about.php, contact.php) and if I upload new WP it will overwrite my old index.php.

Is there anyway I can make it work? Sb goes www.mywebsite.com and is being redirected for example on www.mywebsite.com/old/index.php?

And only from my IP (static) I have normal access to www.mywebsite.com to get the configuration done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect to all IP's but mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985502/htaccess-redirect-to-all-ips-but-mine)

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try this and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming your using apache)

Use a new VirtualHost (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

if you want both to be assiible from the same domain at the same time, you will need either a subdomain or a change of port, Both are doable with the above block of code.

You will need to either `reload` or restart `apache` for the changes to take place